# CFRelease with ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I am finally updating an application to Xcode 4.5 and ARC. I'm having a few problems.
At several points in the code I use `CFRelease()` for values returned by `CFxxCopyxx()` functions.

However, with the `CFRelease()`, I get a

> *** -[CFURL class]: message sent to deallocated instance at runtime.

If I remove the `CFRelease()`, I get a compile warning about Object leaked which makes sense to me. What am I missing?

```
char path[PATH_MAX]={0};
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
if (NULL != mainBundle)
{
    CFURLRef resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(mainBundle);
    if (!CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(resourcesURL, TRUE, (UInt8 *)path, PATH_MAX))
    {
        NSLog(@)"CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation() failed.\n");
    }
    CFRelease(resourcesURL);
}else
{
    NSLog(@"CFBundleGetMainBundle() failed.\n");
}
```

Comment: 3 months and no answer!!!! Reason, wrong tag.... atleast tag to cocoa or objective-c, someone will read....

Comment: try writing `if(resourcesURL) CFRelease(resourcesURL);`

Comment: Have you run the analyzer on your code?  Choose Product > Analyze from the menu bar.  The analyzer tends to get better with every release so you should run it using the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: i think you need the `CFRelease`, also which line did the error occur? the line of `CFRelease`?

Comment: Any reason why `-[NSBundle resourcePath]` can't be used? It would be less code to have to deal with.

Comment: As with BergQuestor, the `-[NSBundle resourcePath]` call would be fine, especially when written like this: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`. You can also cast many CoreFoundation objects to Foundation/Objective C, via `CFBridgingRelease()`.